# Joomla 2.5 joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join, joomla

I am trying to join 3 tables and store the result.
The problem is I simply cannot seem to deal with it. Hours of Googling and searching led to nothing.

Here is the query:

```
 $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $item_kit = array();

    $q = "SELECT p.virtuemart_product_id,
              pr.product_price,
              pr.virtuemard_product_id,
              pb.group_id
       FROM #_virtuemart_products p
           INNER JOIN #_virtuemart_product_prices pr ON p.virtuemart_product_id = pr.virtuemart_product_id,
           INNER JOIN #_pb_group_vm_prod_xref pb ON pb.vm_product_id = pr.virtuemart_product_id";

    $db->setQuery($q);
    $item_kit = $db->loadObjectList();
    return $item_kit;
```

Please notice that I am using the ID as the common element in all tables.
After all this nonsense occurs it should so something like:

```
if(!empty($item_kit['group_id'])){
      echo 'It works';
}
```

Debugging resulted in discovering an SQL error near '`INNER JOIN #_virtuemart_product_prices pr ON p.virtuemart_product_id = pr.virtu...`'

Can you please help me? Or, at least, point out where am I doing stupidly wrong...
I know it's something small and easy, but I can't see it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem!
`pr.virtuemard_product_id` to `pr.virtuemart_product_id`
and I had to manually type in the database table prefix.
What silly of me. Thank you all for your time reading this question.
Regards,
Vlad

Comment: First the generic prefix is "#__" not "#_" which is why it was not picking it up. Second especially if you don't know sql you should be using as much of the JDatabaseQuery api as you can.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed the missing _ from the prefix... Thanks for the input !

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma at the end of the first inner join line

```
INNER JOIN #_virtuemart_product_prices ... pr.virtuemart_product_id,
```

it should become

```
INNER JOIN #_virtuemart_product_prices ... pr.virtuemart_product_id
```

Comment: I removed that comma but the problem persists. "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN #_virtuemart_product_prices pr ON p.virtuemart_product_id = pr.virtue' at line 6"